# Background-image transition section

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a "transition" effect between 2 sections with a background-image.

My 2 sections have two different colors, I wish to add a cloud image to hide the sudden break between my sections.

The catch is that a background-image always remains in its container. How do I overlay it with the other section?

Thank you.

```css
section {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.section1 {
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ee/9b/68/ee9b684ce8d166359272309ca2504037.png');
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section section1">
  <h1>Red Section</h1>
</section>

<section class="section section2">
  <h1>Blue section</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: So you want to top half of the clouds to be red and the bottom half blue?

Comment: Yes, exactly ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using pseudo elements such as ::before in combination with z-index and positioning (x and y)

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the background image to the body, then lower the opacity on each of the sections to let the image bleed through both of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
section {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.section1 {
  /* background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-   ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ee/9b/68/ee9b684ce8d166359272309ca2504037.png');
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.section2 {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
 margin-top: -20px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.test {
  background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ee/9b/68/ee9b684ce8d166359272309ca2504037.png');
  //background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  //background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <section class="section section1">
     <h1>Red Section</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="section section2">
     <h1>Blue section</h1>
    </section>
</div>
```